# How to serve unknown file types from IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, mime

Is there a way to serve unknown file types in IIS 7?

I only want to do this for a single directory where execution is turned off and everything will be served as a static file.

As it is now, I have to add each file extension that I want to serve as a MIME type. I want to serve everything. How can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add an universal MIME type by using the extension "*" and the type "application/octet-stream": http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965

Comment: Click MIME Types.
Click New.
In the Extension box, type an asterisk (*).
In the MIME Type box, type `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of going through the MMC like the kb article suggests, you can also just create a Web.config file in the directory, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".*" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case pictures help. This is for IIS v10 installed on a windows 10 box:

1. Go to MIME Types feature of the virtual directory of your website:

[image]

2. Set up the asterisk based mime type to support unknown file types:

[image]